# How does printf in c++ process the arguments that are passed to it?

Tags: c++, c, parsing, printf

I have been trying to understand how printf processes the arguments that are passed to it. To be more specific can someone please explain how the following outputs occour.

```
int a=1;
printf("%d %d %d",++a,a,a++);// outputs: 3 3 1

a=1;
printf("%d %d %d",a++,a,a++);// outputs: 2 3 1

a=1;
printf("%d %d %d",a,a,a++);// outputs: 2 2 1

a=1;
printf("%d %d %d",a,a++,a);// outputs: 2 1 2

a=1;    
printf("%d %d %d",a,a,++a);// outputs: 2 2 2
```

the same output occurs with the `cout` statement.

Comment: Ah..... it's been too long. (And this has *nothing* to do with `printf`.)

Comment: Order of evaluation of the parameter is not fixed.

Comment: @KerrekSB It's not quite up there with `while ( !file.eof() )...`, but it's close.  (Of course, the answer to the question in the title is: it uses `<stdarg.h>`.  But that's not the question he actually asks.)

Answer (score 4):

This code

```
printf("%d %d %d",++a,a,a++);// outputs: 3 3 1
```

modifies a twice in the same expression. To be precise it modifies a twice without an intervening *sequence point*. Because of this this code has *undefined behaviour* and any attempt to reason about it is futile. The compiler can do what it wants, and different compilers will do different things. See [undefined behavior and sequence points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points) for a detailed explanation.

With code like this

```
printf("%d %d %d",a,a,a++);// outputs: 2 2 1
```

it's undefined exactly when a++ is incremented, it could be before or after a is used for the other arguments. So your output could vary.

The only real thing to understand here is **don't write code like this**. Follow that rule and you won't go wrong.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, "sequence point" is mentioned in C++03, but was reworded in C++11. Some rules (including this one?) changed as well. I see @sftrabbit's answer concurs with this, and it is not undefined behavior in C++11 if I'm not missing something (which is very well possible).

Comment: @rubenvb I haven't kept up with C++11 but sftrabbit says it's undefined in C++11 as well.

Comment: @rubenvb - the terminology changed, but the goal was to leave the underlying rules the same for single-threaded code.

Comment: 5) i = ++i + 1 ; //well defined behaviour
6) ++++i ; in c++11! the above link says this

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't have anything to do with how `printf` and `cout` work. The C++ standard defines an ordering over the evaluation of expressions and their side effects. The wording changed a bit between C++03 and C++11, but it currently describes the evaluation of function arguments as being *unsequenced*. That is, you have no guarantee over the order in which a functions arguments will be executed.

Since you use the value of `a` and modify `a` in two expressions that are unsequenced, you have undefined behaviour.

> If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either anotherside effect on the same scalar object or a value computation using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is undefined.